# what is the purpose A in square brackets in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, brackets

I am newly learning Scala.  below code has [A] multiple times. Please, someone, explain me in layman terms. I am unable to understand(tried google and read  StackOverflow and others answers but I don't get it. The code below is to find kth element from the list.

```html
def findKth[A](k:Int, l:List[A]):A = k match {
    case 0 => l.head
    case k if k > 0 => findKth(k - 1, l.tail)
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException  
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def findKth[A](k:Int, l:List[A]):A = k match {
    case 0 => l.head
    case k if k > 0 => findKth(k - 1, l.tail)
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException  
}
```

Here `[A]` is the type parameter for function `findKth`. Now what does type parameter mean?
Type parameter tells the compiler that method `findKth` can take parameter of type `A`. Which is the generic type here because `A` can be anything. For example `A` can be `Int`, `Double`, another `List` -- anything.

For more information I would suggest you to go through these links:

> https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html
>
> https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html

Answer (score 4):

It is for declaring generic parameters in Scala, You can call your method with a list of different types (`Double`, `Int`, `Dogs` ... )

If you want to learn more, this post: https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/scala-type-bounds/

For example:

```
def findKth[A](k:Int, l:List[A]):A = k match {
    case 0 => l.head
    case k if k > 0 => findKth(k - 1, l.tail)
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException  
}

val intList = 1 :: 2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10::Nil
val strList = intList.map(_.toString)
println(findKth(9, intList))
println(findKth(3, strList))
```

As you can see, you can pass to your function a `List[Int]`, or a `List[String]`, it is a way to parametrize functions to accept generics arguments.

You can see it working in here: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/XwaALIk/0

Comment: you can explain it more as OP is really new to scala. :)

Comment: @RamanMishra Done, I am sorry.

Comment: @EIBauIP no need to sorry that's fine your answer is correct. (Y)